# What's the encoding type of Android 2.2 push message?

Tags: android, encoding, android-c2dm

I'm studying Android push service (C2DM) for Android Froyo version.
The Google says the max size of message is 1024 bytes (http://code.google.com/intl/ko/android/c2dm/).
What is the message encoding type? I want to put extra message which is not English.

Answer (score 2):

C2DM requires your application to send messages url-encoded with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I can confirm that it works well for data with german umlauts + ß.